# compilation with Makefile fail but success in command line

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile, raspberry-pi

I was using a Makefile to compile my project and compiled successfully, but when I added a new lib (libbcm2835.a) to linker (-lbcm2835) it fails, otherwise when using the following commands it compile and link with no error :

```
gcc -c ihome_*.c
gcc -o iHome_Start ihome*.o -lbcm2835 -lpthread
```

Makefile :

```
# project name (generate executable with this name)
TARGET   = iHome_Start

CC       = gcc
# compiling flags here
CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -Wall -I.

LINKER   = gcc -o
# linking flags here
LFLAGS   = -lpthread -lbcm2835

# change these to set the proper directories where each files shoould be
SRCDIR   = .
OBJDIR   = .
BINDIR   = .

SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm       = rm -f


$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONEY: clean
clean:
    @$(rm) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"

.PHONEY: remove
remove: clean
    @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @echo "Executable removed!"
```

Comment: What is the error message when compiling with the makefile?

Comment: the order you link in the libraries is different. Try `LFLAGS   = -lbcm2835 -lpthread` like your manual compilation.

Comment: you missed the flag `-std=c99` in the command line.

Comment: `-o` is to give the name of the output file. `-o`is used as if it meant calling the linker (I'm not sure on where the confusion is, but the usage of `-o` looks quite wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in

```
@$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
```

The linker processes the arguments in an order they appear. By the time it sees the libraries, it hadn't yet seen no object files, hence there are no unresolved symbols, hence it pulls nothing from the libraries. Swap `$(OBJECTS)` and `$(LFLAGS)`:

```
@$(LINKER) $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS)
```

I would also recommend to rename `LFLAGS` to `LIBRARIES`.

Comment: Great ! it works : Swaping $(OBJECTS) and $(LFLAGS) ! thank you